# Passing an argument to a method inherited by an instance

Tags: javascript, binding, this

The goal of this code is create a simple biz (business) profile, using a constructor that inherits the method `print` and a constructor that allows to render biz information, based on that method, plus something extra (`size`).
The expected output is "The core of Hexis is tech" 2. Instead, I'm getting "The core of undefined is undefined" 2.

How to make the first argument of the `bizOneHexis`(instance of `PrintBizInfo`) pass as the argument of `this` in the inherited `print` method?

```
const bizDataBase = [
  {name: "Hexis", core: "tech"},
  {name: "Lexia", core: "consulting"}
  ]

function PrintBizCore (print){
  this.print = function (){
    //I want to pass bizDataBase[0] as the context of this.name etc.
    console.log(`The core of ${this.name} is ${this.core}` );
  }
  this.print();
}

function PrintBizInfo (print, size){
  PrintBizCore.call(this, print);
  this.size = 'Its size is ' + size;
}

let bizOneHexis = new PrintBizInfo (bizDataBase[0], 2); //-> The core of undefined is undefined
console.log(bizOneHexis.size); //-> "Its size is 2"
```

I got the expected result modifying the code like this:

```
const bizDataBase = [
  {name: "Hexis", core: "tech"},
  {name: "Lexia", core: "consulting"}
  ]

function PrintBizCore (print){
  this.print = function (){
    console.log(`The core of ${bizDataBase[0].name} is ${bizDataBase[0].core}` );
  }
  this.print();
}

function PrintBizInfo (print, size){
  PrintBizCore.call(this, print);
  this.size = 'Its size is ' + size;
}

let bizOneHexis = new PrintBizInfo (bizDataBase[0], 2); //-> "The core of Hexis is tech"
console.log(bizOneHexis.size); //-> "Its size is 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code above. It doesn't respond some of my questions, but solves how to get the desired output (I think this is little bit interesting for programmers working in projects similar to Bloomberg services. Anyways:

```
function PrintBizCore (print){
  this.print = function (){
    console.log(`The core of ${this.name} is ${this.core}` );
  }
  this.print();
}

const bizDataBase = [
  {name: "Hexis", core: "tech"}, {name: "Lexia", core: "consulting"}
  ];

function printer (obj){
  obj.forEach(function(brand){
    return PrintBizCore.call(brand)
  })
}

printer(bizDataBase);
//-> "The core of Hexis is tech"
//-> "The core of Lexia is consulting"
```